# Closed subgroup of a semisimple Lie group

Tags: lie-groups

If $H\subset{G}$ is a topologically closed subgroup of a compact, connected and semisimple Lie group G, then is $H$ also semisimple? If yes, I need some references where this is stated.

Comment: Let $H$ be a Cartan subgroup of $G$. Then $H$ is abelian.

Comment: Yes, by definition. But, how is this related to my question? Or is it too obvious for you and you are just fooling around?

Comment: I thought that abelian Lie groups are not semisimple? Why do you say fooling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In fact every compact semisimple Lie group has at least one non-semisimple closed subgroup: a maximal torus. For a specific example, take the diagonal subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$.

(A torus is not semisimple since it is abelian, and hence it's Lie algebra has non-trivial solvable ideals.)